# Select call only working on tcp inputs twice. How to properly use select with tcp and udp server?

Tags: python, sockets, select, tcp, udp

I am creating a server which using select() for non-blocking i/o in Python.

I have a server which has select with inputs being a TCP connection and a UDP connection. Within the TCP connection, there may be calls to other UDP servers.
The problem is that my server only checks for TCP input twice when I am running the server and some data transfer with other UDP servers (not the server's own UDP sever) takes place. If there is no need for UDP transfer then there it is working as many times as it is invoked by the web browser.

My server seems to be working fine other than that weird situation where I can only send the TCP request twice.

I also suspect that I am able to send it twice because of some favicon request and actual request by the browser which is making 's' twice as inputs and isn't working after it. I also think that there might be an issue on how I am using select for server's own UDP connection.

This is my first time writing a server program so there might be some straightforward issue with how I am dealing with select function and sockets in general.

```
inputs = [ server, udp ]

# Sockets to which we expect to write
outputs = [ ]

# Outgoing message queues (socket:Queue)
message_queues = {}

while inputs:
    # Wait for at least one of the sockets to be ready for processing
    print('\nwaiting for the next event')
    readable, writable, exceptional = select.select(inputs, outputs, inputs)
```

This is somewhat how my loop for readable inputs look:

```
        if s is server:
            connection, client_address = s.accept()
            connection.setblocking(0)
            inputs.append(connection)
            message_queues[connection] = queue.Queue()
        elif s != udp:
            print(readable)
            try:
                data = s.recv(4096)
                if data:
                    # do something
                    message_queues[s].put(data)
                    if s not in outputs:
                        outputs.append(s)
                else:
                    # Interpret empty result as closed connection
                    print('closing', client_address, 'after reading no data')
                    if s in outputs:
                        outputs.remove(s)
                    inputs.remove(s)
                    s.close()
                    del message_queues[s]
            except Exception:
                if s in outputs:
                    outputs.remove(s)
                inputs.remove(s)
                s.close()
        if s is udp:
            print(s)
            udpdata,addr = s.recvfrom(UDP_PORT_NO)
```

This is somewhat how my loop for writeable looks:

```
for s in writable:
        try:
            next_msg = message_queues[s].get_nowait()

            if (something):
                udp_others = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
                try:
                    # Send data
                    sent = udp_others.sendto(packet.encode(), ('localhost', destination_port))
                    # Receive response
                    clientdata, server = udp_test.recvfrom(4096)
                    # do something with data
                finally:
                    print ('closing socket')
                    udp_others.close()

            next_msg = "Hello"
        except queue.Empty:
            # No messages waiting so stop checking for writability.
            print('output queue for', s.getpeername(), 'is empty')
            outputs.remove(s)
        else:
            print(response)

    # Handle "exceptional conditions"
    for s in exceptional:
        print >>sys.stderr, 'handling exceptional condition for', s.getpeername()
        # Stop listening for input on the connection
        inputs.remove(s)
        if s in outputs:
            outputs.remove(s)
        s.close()

        # Remove message queue
        del message_queues[s]
```

Comment: I think that the issues are with some sockets or select implementation on Python because a replicate server in Java is having no such issues as Python server. I am assuming that my logic of content of my server is correct.

Comment: I was able to fix it. There were some small issues with variables naming.